# Straight line EasingFunction in WPF application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-animation

### Straight line EasingFunction in WPF application

I am working in WPF application and new to animation. I need to animate images in straight direction with ease effect. Which type of EasingFunction can I use? Now I am using CircleEase function but not moving in straight line. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ease function:
QuadraticEase, CubicEase, QuarticEase, QuinticEase, PowerEase, BackEase, BounceEase, CircleEase, ElasticEase, ExponentialEase, SineEase.

Otherwise, you can write your own ease function. You create a class that implements IEasingFunction

For example:

```
public class LinearEase : IEasingFunction
{
   public double Ease(double normalizedTime)
   {
      return normalizedTime;
   }
}
```